# Shouldn't GaussianBlur be symmetric?

Tags: c++, opencv, gaussian

I expected a Gaussian Blur operation to be symmetric, but using the OpenCV 2.4.11 `GaussianBlur` I am getting differences.

Here's an example. I apply a `GaussianBlur` to an image, and to a flipped version of the image. I've separately verified the `flip` operation doesn't change the image pixel values (not shown). When I flip the blurred image back, I expected it to be the same as the blur of the original, but the `diff` shows a lot of small differences (between 0.0 and 6.103515625e-005). I know that's small, but it has a knock-on effect in my subsequent processing.

The Gaussian Kernel is symmetric, so the result should be the same. Is this simply a rounding error in the implementation?

```
int main(int, char **)
{
    // e.g. 2008_005541.jpg from VOC2012 dataset
    char const * const filename = "...";
    float const sig_diff = 1.24899971f;

    cv::Mat image = cv::imread(filename, cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    cv::Mat gray_fpt;
    image.convertTo(gray_fpt, cv::DataType<float>::type, 1, 0);
    GaussianBlur(gray_fpt, gray_fpt, cv::Size(), sig_diff, sig_diff);

    cv::Mat mirror;
    flip(image, mirror, 1);
    cv::Mat mirror_gray_fpt;
    mirror.convertTo(mirror_gray_fpt, cv::DataType<float>::type, 1, 0);
    GaussianBlur(mirror_gray_fpt, mirror_gray_fpt, cv::Size(), sig_diff, sig_diff);

    flip(mirror_gray_fpt, mirror_gray_fpt, 1);
    cv::Mat diff = abs(gray_fpt - mirror_gray_fpt);
    double minval, maxval;
    minMaxLoc(diff, &minval, &maxval);

    // minval = 0.0;
    // maxval = 6.103515625e-005;

    // easier to visualise the differences with this:
    normalize(diff, diff, 0.0, 1.0, cv::NORM_MINMAX, CV_32FC1);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I changed the type from `cv::DataType<float>::type` to `cv::DataType<double>::type` and now the max error is 1.1368683772161603e-013, so rounding seems to be the problem.

Comment: I'm assuming it's rounding, too, but not enough of an OpenCV expert to confirm it. But if you need a symmetric operation, how about copying the image, flip, blur, flip back, and average with the directly blurred image? Of course, you might need to check flips in both directions.

Comment: this is a small step in my pipeline, and I don't know the orientation of the image, so can't determine whether to flip or not. But I do want the same values regardless of the horizontal orientation

Comment: 6.103515625e-005 is pretty close to the rounding error for floats

Comment: @cdmh always do the flip and average both results.  Regardless.  Note, however, that all floating point steps are going to accumulate 'error' like this: you need to deal with that possibility in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the code above to call `gaussian_blur` (below) instead of `GaussianBlur` produces no differences in the example images I've tested so far.

From this, if the working type of the Gaussian operation is `double` precision, then the output in `float`ing point precision yields no error. That seems like a nice solution to my problem.

```
// Perform gaussian blur in double precision and convert back
void gaussian_blur(
    cv::Mat const &src, cv::Mat &dst,
    cv::Size ksize, double sigmaX, double sigmaY=0,
    int borderType=cv::BORDER_DEFAULT)
{
    cv::Mat src_dp;
    src.convertTo(src_dp, cv::DataType<double>::type, SIFT_FIXPT_SCALE, 0);

    cv::Mat dst_dp;
    GaussianBlur(src_dp, dst_dp, ksize, sigmaX, sigmaY, borderType);

    dst_dp.convertTo(dst, src.type(), SIFT_FIXPT_SCALE, 0);
}
```